# Issue installing BlackBerry Plug-in for Android Development on Eclipse

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I am trying to install the "BlackBerry Plug-in for Android Development", and receiving the below error in the end:

Anyone please whats wrong with this ?

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context wasprofile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,21.0.0.v201210310015-519525
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,21.0.0.v201210310015-519525
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,21.0.0.v201210310015-519525
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,21.0.0.v201210310015-519525
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,21.0.0.v201210310015-519525
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,21.0.0.v201210310015-519525
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,21.0.0.v201210310015-519525
```

Comment: Did you see the plugins already installed if it has any older versions?